# Cos'è un "babaccetto"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Cosí bambina (una bambina mai cresciuta, ripeteva il fratello sconsolato), che a Natale per vederla sorridere dovevi regalarle peluche, *babaccetti* di stoffa colorati, macchinine e soldatini da collezione;

Ho cercato il significato di "babaccetto", ma non l'ho trovato. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dialetto piemontese ***[babaciu](http://protorino.altervista.org/pdf/piemontese-base.pdf)*** significa :

> - pupazzo, fantoccio

Penso si tratti di un diminutivo/vezzeggiativo  del termine dialettale  visto che la scrittrice [Paola Mastrocola](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paola_Mastrocola) è  di Torino.